# How to get templates always before models in Rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have Angular service where need to conditionally map models using templateForPercentage or templateForCurrency it only in case addExpensesItemCurrency and addExpensesItemPercent subscription get response BEFORE this.getExpensesGroups(id) gets response. What operator or combination of operators would u suggest to use to get both templates AND value emitted by `switchMap(id => this.getExpensesGroups(id))` row:

```
templateForCurrency$ = new BehaviorSubject<Model>(null);
templateForPercentage$ = new BehaviorSubject<Model>(null);
templateForPercentage: Model;
templateForCurrency: Model;

constructor() {
  this.projectIdState$.pipe(
    tap(p => console.log('fetched expenses for project', p)),
    tap(id => { if (!id || id === "admin-areas") this.expensesState = initialExpensesState }),
    filter(id => id && id !== "admin-areas"),
    switchMap(id => this.getExpensesGroups(id))

    // i guess here should be some operators to get templates
    // this.templateForCurrency$.pipe(
    //   switchMap(template => template ? Observable.of(template) : this.addExpensesItemCurrency())
  // )  

  // this.templateForPercent$.pipe(
    //   switchMap(template => template ? Observable.of(template) : this.addExpensesItemPercent())
  // )  

  // I guess it should return something like that  [ExpenseGroup, templateForCurrency, templateForPercent]

  }).subscribe((response: ExpenseGroup[]) => {
    this.expensesState = {
      ...this.expensesState,
      expenseGroupsToExpose: [...response.map(g => ({
        ...g, models: g.models.map(m => this.mapExpenseModel(m))
      }))],
      isLoading: false
    }})

    this.addExpensesItemCurrency().subscribe(
      template => this.templateForCurrency = template
    )

    this.addExpensesItemPercent().subscribe(
      template => this.templateForPercentage = template
    )
  }
}

private mapExpenseModel(model) {
  const template = this.setTemplate(model.subType);

  return {
    ...model,
    ...template,
    initialSubType: model.subType,
    shouldSave: true
  }
}

private setTemplate(subType: string) {
  if (subType === "EXPENSE_ABS_CURRENCY") {
    return {template: this.templateForPercentage.fields};
  } else if (subType === "EXPENSE_ABS_PERCENT") {
    return {template: this.templateForCurrency.fields};
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain of what you're trying to achieve here. Could you provide a simplified example with a play-by-play of exactly the behaviour you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `forkJoin` and result selector in `switchMap` you can combine all the result together and deliver to the subsequence stream

```
...
switchMap(id => this.getExpensesGroups(id))
switchMap(template=>forkJoin(
       this.addExpensesItemPercent(),
       this.addExpensesItemCurrency()),res=>[template,...res]
    )
...
```

Comment: So far so good, but i get result of last switchMap like this `[arrayOfExpensesGroups, templateForPercent]` , but should  return `[arrayOfExpensesGroups, templateForPercent, templateForCurrency]`

Comment: updated the answer see if it works, i forgot to include addExpensesItemCurrency

Comment: It seems strange I still get the same result  [arrayOfExpensesGroups, templateForPercent]. If I change sequence of currency and percent  like that `switchMap(template=> forkJoin(
        this.addExpensesItemCurrency(), this.addExpensesItemPercent(),
      ),res=>[template,...res]
    )`

I get result [arrayOfExpensesGroups, templateForCurrency] and no templateForPercentage

Comment: Perhaps issue with this.addExpensesItemPercent() and this.addExpensesItemCurrency() methods .They look like
`addExpensesItemCurrency() {
    return this.http
      .get(this.appService.getBaseUrl()+'/api/template/expenseABS' )
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }`

Comment: Perhaps you can try add tap to debug the data returned 
```forkJoin(
       this.addExpensesItemPercent(),
       this.addExpensesItemCurrency()).pipe(tap(console.log)), ```
i think it is a matter of composing the right data structure